# Launch Images in iOS 7 with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I've been setting my own names on launch images for my apps in the Info.plist like

[image: Info.plist setup for Launch images]

with the following images in bundle (with correct dimensions, 320x480 px for default.png and 640x960 px for default@2x.png etc.)

[image: Launch images in bundle]

this have been working great prior to iOS 7 and Xcode 5. Now when I look in the General tab for the corresponding target in Xcode 5 my launch image files get mixed up from other targets in my project, which worries me, even though I haven't seen wrong launch image files when actually running the target. Should I be worried? The chosen images isn't in the build target so I should be fine there, but is there a risk of getting a blank image instead?

[image: Launch images part of the General tab in Xcode 5]

My main question is, can I use my default setup in Info.plist (that help auto detected respective launch images) for iOS 7, and if so, what should I name the corresponding launch images (now that there's the "iOS 6.1 and Prior" options as well with different dimensions)? This especially applies for the iPad Portrait Retina (iOS 7) that has new dimensions. The auto detection on iPad Portrait Non-Retina (iOS 7) refers to an image, not in the build target, that has the right dimensions. Again, when running a simulator with iPad Retina and iOS 7.0 the correct launch image shows.

Comment: could you explain how you meant _my launch image files get mixed up from other targets in my project_, please?

Comment: It's a project with 10 or so different targets, all with the same naming convention, so there are multiple launch images with the name "default.png", but only one (unique) per target. Even though I'm in the General tab for one target, Xcode finds files not in the target membership, so when clicking the "eye"-button or checking the path for launch images they show files from other targets. Earlier, prior to Xcode 5, the images we're shown as actual images instead of textual (as above third image) and then they we're always correct.

Comment: @Anden87...will you please help me to set launch image for iphone 4 and 5. As I tried but It is not displaying in iphone 4

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Anden, I ran into the same problem today while adding a new target to the half dozen I already had that were set up in the same way that you set up yours.

I decided to use that "Use Asset Catalog" button, which took some work to set up, but has simplified things greatly in the end:

1- (optional) Delete (remove references only) the icon and launch image files from your project. I don't think you need the files to be in the project navigator anymore.

2- Choose your primary target, go to "General" and "App Icons" (as you showed above).

3- Press the "Use Asset Catalog" button, with the "Migrate Launch Images" checked as well.

4- This creates a file called "Images.xcassets" in your project navigator. Go there, and find the App Icon and Launch Image catalogs corresponding with the particular target. You can drag and drop image files from the finder into the slots in the catalog, and rename the icon/default groups from the list on the left.

5- Once you've got the image slots filled up, go back to the "General" for each target, and press the "Use Asset Catalog" button again for each target. Instead of creating a new xcassets file for each, you can store all the launch images and icon files in the same xcassets file.

Comment: Thanks, we use this method and it works on the iPad.  Strangely we are NOT seeing the images on the iPhone 4 or 5.

Comment: @MobileVet same here.. not even using asset catalog. still not being able to get both 3.5 and 4 inch iphone/ipod launch images working. ipad works just fine.

Comment: Xcode 5 *clearly* prefers the asset catalog approach. Thanks for this.

Comment: I got a version of the problem: each time I added a portrait image it said the (previously OK) landscape image was the wrong size and vice versa! Using the asset catalog fixed it.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu...can you tell me how to set for iphone 4 and 5 launch images

Comment: This is not an option, if you need to localize your launch images since there is no way to localise asset catalogues

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bug in xcode 5. I filed a bug, perhaps you should too (bugreport.apple.com). Make Apple aware things like this are not working well, and are taking our time and nerves.

Comment: What's the Radar # of the bug you reported?