# Black screen instead of launch image on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am developing an iPhone app for iOS 6.1 and 7 (using Xcode 5). I have a problem with iPad launch images.

On iPad 7.0 and 7.0.2, the launch image is not showing up(in 6.1 works!): I get black screen while app is loading.

I don't face this issue with iPhone 6.1 and 7.0.2, although I set all launch images required for iPad and iPad retina (landscape and portrait) and I use Asset Catalog.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you clean your project before running it? Also alt+shift+cmd+k to clean your build director.

Comment: Done,but still not working! :(

Comment: Have you checked that images used as splashscreen are targeted in your project?

Comment: Delete all your splash images from your project and try to re-add them. Also do you have Images.xcassets "folder" in your project? Like in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758882/launch-images-in-ios-7-with-xcode-5

Comment: You had already thought that probably but you can use your own custom SplashScreen by creating a custom view when application did finish launching with options and it appears for a while, then you can go to your root view controller.

Comment: You say **I am developing an iPhone app for iOS 6.1 and 7 (using Xcode 5). I have a problem with iPad launch images.** have you actually added the correct images. Have you named them correctly? Here is a link for dimensions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html and here is a link for names and dimensions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

Comment: Check this post to get the solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913274/883505

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I requested Apple support and it turned out that it's a bug. They asked me to report it and I did. Here is the report id : 15340531. 
Now it's up to them.

Answer (score 33):

Recently I faced same issue with my App designed only for iPhone , I had the problem where the launch images would not appear in iPad (On iPad ios >= 7.0.x the launch image is not showing up I get black screen while app is loading (in iPad ios < 7.0.x it works fine )).

I don't face this issue of launch image with iPhone worked fine in all iOS versions.

**Solution**: Is to update to asset catalog to manage your app's images and target only iOS 6 and Prior.

Steps :

Step 1:

[image: Update to Asset Catalog]

Step 2:

[image: Select to Migrate]

Step 3: on the top right corner click on the 'Attribute Inspector' icon. Here you can set the Target OS for the Launch Images.

[image: Uncheck the iOS 7 check boxes for iPhone]

Uncheck the iOS 7 check boxes for iPhone, Now you should be able to see the launch images for  iPad on iOS >= 7.0.x.

Comment: nice workaround for now but I added another bug report with apple

Comment: Works but I now get a warning: Images.xcassets: An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 7.0 and later is required.  I guess this is ok for now.  Hope this issue gets fixed by Apple.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be slightly buggy in Xcode. I was concerned "migrating" would screw up my existing asset catalog but it just added a new entry to it containing the default black screens that I just deleted and all is good. It's strange that you need to do this pointless migrate step, but it had no negative consequences for me.

Answer (score 24):

If you have the same situation like mine, that's solution:

My app is landscape only, iOs7 only, ipad\iphone (XCode 5).

**Problem:** black launch on iphone (and simulator), normal launch in ipad.

**Solution**: go to Images.xcassets - Launch Images - select it. Uncheck at right all *"iOs7 and later"* boxes. Check *"iOs6 and prior"* boxes and fill empty spaces with images.

Strange, but works.

Comment: This makes absolutely so sense, but it absolutely works. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me, but it makes SOME launch image show up, so you're on the right track

Comment: This works great, but now I get a warning "An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 7.0 and later is required."

Comment: +1 This has been doing my head in for the last couple hours. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Per Apple's documentation ([link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1780/&ei=nAxXUuX7Iceu4AOb6oHYCw&usg=AFQjCNEfjEhQONRhekmE8MqNoQyGRo_I2g&sig2=z41UuYAM2FgXzE3_dJQEiA&bvm=bv.53760139,d.dmg)); an empty iPad specific storyboard may be the answer. I've also seen issues where the initial view controller is not set within a storyboard causes a black screen. A variant of this issue might be an incorrect setting in the app plist.

Technical Q&A QA1780
Why does my app launch to a black screen on iPad?

Q:  Why does my app launch to a black screen on iPad?

A: Apps that have been designed only for iPhone may launch to a blank screen when run on an iPad. This is caused by the presence of an empty iPad specific storyboard in the app bundle as well as an iPad specific UIMainStoryboardFile key in the app's Information Property List (Info.plist) file. Both are automatically created by the various Xcode template projects if the Universal option is selected.

...

In Xcode

Look for a file named MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard in the file navigator. If this file is present, remove it from your project.

In your app's Information Property List

Look for a key named Main storyboard file base name (iPad) or UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad. If this key is present, remove it. You should also remove any other key suffixed with (iPad) or ~ipad.

Finally, test your app on an iPad or in the iPad simulator and verify that it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 7):

## Using LaunchScreen.storyboard

I was having a similar problem until I found the following settings in the **General Project Settings**.

1. Set your **Main Interface** to your main storyboard file. Mine is called `Main.storyboard`.

[image]

2. Set your **Launch Screen File** to your launch screen storyboard file. Mine is called `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. (This is what I had originally ommited.)

[image]

After that the launch screen loaded first and then the main story board loaded shortly later.

Answer (score 4):

Try set the image again make sure that resolution of the splash screen is according to the iOS 7 guidelines

Answer (score 3):

I know this sounds stupid. I've had bugs like that when I saved a file in psd-format with a jpg extension. Just 1 wrong click while saving your launch image.

Comment: this is a good one to look out for... happened in the past to me too. however, it didn't solve it for me this time though...

Answer (score 3):

After having tried several solutions found here, I suspected that the iPhone was trying to launch in Landscape orientation, and thus not finding any corresponding launch image. Indeed, the simulator was starting in Landscape for a reason I was not understanding.

Finally, after reading Apple documentation, I found that it's probably the order of keys in "Supported interface orientations" of the info.plist file that was not adequate. The Portrait was the last item. When it's the first item, the app launch in Portrait mode and find the image.

Answer (score 2):

Remove previously installed app from the device or simulator, Then relaunch the app after clean.

Comment: Remove previously installed app from the device or simulator, quit xcode and simulator. Start again and launch the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem where the launch images would no appear in iPhone (3.5 or 4 inch) in iOS 7, but the iPad had no problems with iOS 7.

Long story short is I disabled the asset catalog for the launch images only.  So I'm adding the launch images the old fashioned way.  That seems to have solved the problem.

I will have to do more testing tomorrow, but it seems the problem is solved (at least in my case).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

in Xcode 5 , make sure thay you add all needed images mentioned in your app target.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that when you are using Asset Catalog, you have ensured that you have the Images.xcassets target membership added correctly. I am mentioning this since if you have multiple targets, looks like you have to add them manually (and you have not provided any screenshots so one can be sure).

Now that you have not really provided a screenshot of the "LaunchImage" overview of Images.xcassets folder in your project, I can only guess the probable reason. Looking at the fact that the launch images work fine for iPhone (6.1 & 7.0.2 and iPad (6.1) and do not work only for iPad (7.0 and upwards), I think you could perhaps look at as to whether the dimension of the images for iPad Portrait and iPad Landscape are proper for iOS7. Specifically, you should see your launch images and not empty rectangles as seen in the attached pic-
[image: iOS7 iPad Launch Images (portrait and landscape)- not correctly sized]

This can happen due to the fact that you still have the iPad launch images for iOS7 created excluding the status bar area. Prior to iOS7, the iPad launch images were created to exclude the status bar area, but it's a must on iOS7 that all the launch images must include the status bar area. Please go through the section "Things Every App Must Do" in Apple iOS7 UI transition Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/TransitionGuide.pdf).

The following screenshot should explain what I am talking about-
[image: iPad launch images dimensions- iOS6 and iOS7]

e.g. you can see that iPad Landscape Retina image dimension for iOS6.1 and previous is 2048x1496 (excluding 40 px for status bar) but the dimension for the same image for iOS7.0 and upwards is expected to be 2048x1536 (including the 40px for status bar). So, if you have not changed your images accordingly, you will see black screen for images on iPad 7.0 and upwards.  On iPhones, you will not face this issue since iPhone launch images always cover the status bar, be it iOS6.0 and iOS7.0- so the new UI requirement is already met for iPhone launch images.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer which worked for our app (iPhone only, but used on iPad): https://stackoverflow.com/a/19448782/1258419

To summarize from that answer:

> How to do it. Go to the asset catalog. And on the top right corner click on the 'Attribute Inspector' icon. Here you can set the Target OS for the Launch Images. Uncheck the iOS 7 check boxes for iPhone. Now you should be able to see the launch images for these devices.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem in landscape, my iOS 7 launch image wasn’t displayed while the iOS 6 did. Mine was the iPhone Retina 3.5” launch image.

Since I have another app in portrait that didn’t share this issue, I did 2 things:

1. In info.plist, under “Supported interface orientations”, I added the
   2 portrait modes as well, and put them before the landscape, like
   this:

   ```
   Item 0: Portrait (top home button)
   Item 1: Portrait (bottom home button)
   Item 2: Landscape (right home button)
   Item 3: Landscape (left home button)
   ```
2. Implemented this method in the View Controller:

   ```
   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
   ```

   }

This works with or without the Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 1):

***This is an update for iOS 8.***

I got the same problem when I tried to add a `LaunchImage` to my iOS 8  app.

Apple enables developers to use a xib, whose default name is `LaunchScreen.xib`, to render the launch view as of iOS 8. I believe developers can use either `LaunchImage` or `LaunchScreen.xib`. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any document describing how to deal with `LaunchImage` after `LaunchScreen.xib` was introduced. I always got a black screen when I tried to use `LaunchImage` as the launch view.

My solution is:

1. Don't think about `LaunchImage`. Use `LaunchScreen.xib`. (You have to keep an empty `LaunchImage` in your Asset Catalog though. I believe it's a bug.)
2. Drag an `UIImageView` to the xib and make the `UIImageView` full screen. *Remember to take the size classes and constraints into account.*
3. Set an image whose resolution is enough for iPhone 6 plus to the `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your all images and see if it is properly placed in the Asset and properly named and sized.

Also check which orientations your are allowing and accordingly add images to the asset.

Comment: -1 as he specifies `iPad` not 4" please read question before answering.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I had to make a workaround: used the Default image for all iOS versions and DELETED the UILaunchImageFile key from info.plist.

I cannot use different launch images for iOS 7 and previous versions, so, I had to use the same "artistic" image for all, instead an image that mimic the first view of the app (which Apple recommends and I prefer), but at least I do not get the black screen anymore.

It looks like the UILaunchImageFile key that allows to use differents launch images for iOS 7 and previous versions is not working properly for Retina iPad in iOS 7.

WARNING:   I am still testing the app, so I don't know if could be some side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue but its solution was simple (in my case).

All I did was following -

1.Add a new file (if you have not added it) Launchscreen.storyboard

2.Get a `UIViewController`, mark it as `Is Initial View Controller` then add a `UIImageView` in it and set a picture which you want to display during launch of your app. Make sure you give this `UIImageView` required constraint.

3.Go to Project->General->App Icons and Launch images and select Launchscreen.storyboard as Launch Screen File (There will be a dropdown for it).

Answer (score 0):

Because of iOS 13 and later, app launch different than earlier versions.

Get the solution from below URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913274/883505

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to call super.loadView() in my view controller...

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
}
```