# 2.2: Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected ios 7.0.3

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 7.0.3, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, your app launches to a black screen.

For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:

- include the complete details of your rejection issues
- prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.

For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.

If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users are seeing.

I am using httpservice to bind RSS and display RSS data in grid. and upon user selection I am showing content of item in label

I have iPad having iOS 5.1.1 and it works absolutely fine for me without any bug.

What are the recovery steps to get rid of this issue? We have worked a lot for this application and we need to get approved by apple asap.

Comment: You to test the app on an iOS device with iOS 7. That is what most users have now.

Comment: This could be helpful ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219291/black-screen-instead-of-launch-image-on-ipad-ios-7-0-x

Comment: @Amar - I have not used splash screen in this package. I directly redirected my app to first view.

Comment: FYI. I had to upgrade to AIR 3.8 to support the latest version of iOS, which at the time was still in Beta. You may want to make sure you are at least on this version, and possibly try 3.9 beta if the problem still persists. A lot of times they will add support for recently released iOS updates into the beta channel.

Comment: Black screen problem solved. For that I have updated my air sdk by AIR 3.9 beta release. 

~ cheers!