# IOS 7 launch image, displaying black screen on device ONLY

Tags: ios7, ios7.1, launchimage

I have checked all the questions /answers related to this issue at least at stakoverflow .but without any success ,so far my issue is - I have created a new app - target IOS 7 and I have added my launchimage and my appIcon  in the image.xcassets folder .
when I launch my app on simulator the launchimae is showing perfectly without any issue but when I run the app on my iphone (iphone 5 , IOS 7.1) a black screen is showing instead of the launchimage 
any help or suggestions will be appriciated ?
cheers,

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219291/black-screen-instead-of-launch-image-on-ipad-ios-7-0-x/20236878#20236878
(edit: inserted direct link to potential answer)

Comment: I have tried this before but it doesn't help me out to find the issue

Comment: You're using storyboards in your app, right? I've faced the same problem in my project with storyboards. But in another project with traditional xibs there is no such issue...

Comment: I found the real cause. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your image.
You could open your image in Preview.app, then show the Inspector (`⌘I`) and look at More Info tab. Wrong image will show you the following info:

[image: wrong image]

and will result a black screen on the device (but will be ok in the Simulator).
And the right one shood look like that:

[image: correct image]

I can't say how to fix wrong images in Photoshop. I found quite an ugly solution:

1. open wrong png in PS;
2. find and open correct png in another tab (make sure the canvas is of right size);
3. select the whole image in the wrong png and copy it;
4. paste the copied image into correct png file;
5. perform `Save As...` command and replace your wrong image with the new one.

Comment: I would like to re-explain my issue , the root cause and the solution -here is my issue :IOS 7 launch image, displaying black screen on device ONLY . root cause:the root cause of having this issue was my default@2x.png image  was  not a valid png image content ,solution: I took  a valid png image and then I have opened and selected my whole image with wrong png content and then copy it to the valid png image and then everything went perfectly . hope this helps anyone struggling with this issue

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my answer :)

Comment: My correctly working images look like Andrey's "incorrect" example, but my INcorrectly working images (launch screen just shows up black) are clearly wrong in Preview inspector -- no PNG tab shows up, so they're probably not formatted right as png's or something. Redid them in PS, now they work fine! Thanks for the direction, Andrey.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers above, the inspector actually tells you the size that it considers valid for use, so tweak it in whatever package before importing. I have many tools but for a quick-and-clean approach, good 'ol preview comes to the rescue if you take time to explore the editing tools

[image: apple help detail]