# iOS 7 black splash bug and app launch size

Tags: ios, ios7, splash-screen

Currently I am having troubles with a project I am working on.

First of I have this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219291/black-screen-instead-of-launch-image-on-ipad-ios-7-0-x). Where the splash screen on iOS 7 is black when I set a splash screen for iOS 7 devices. The tip which I found there (and which works) is to only set splash screens voor iOS 6 and it will fetch those for iOS 7.

However, when doing this the app launches as an 3.5" app on an 4" device on iOS7. (The splash screen is full size).

I have tried using the old methods to have splash screens (e.g with correct naming conventions) and not using the Image Catalogs, but this doesn't change anything.

[image: My settings]

What can I do to have and a working splash screen on iOS 7 devices and the correct launch size for those devices?

It might be worth noting that this is a Universal app.

Comment: so what is the size of the splash screen you using? 320x480 or 320x568? are you using storyboards? is you app based on iphone or iPad or universal

Comment: Universal, and for the iPhone with 3.5" screen and 4" screen e.g 640*960 and 640*1136. I did fix the problem. I start the app in landscape (and the splash screen works) and my initial controller loads the "real" controller for the app modal without an animation. And that one uses the Landscape only rotation mask. It is a workaround, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a new project and set all image sizes?

There could be a problem with your `Info.plist` after changing the splash images many times.

Comment: I did try that, there I had the exact same problem.

Comment: It could be helpful to share this bare test project. Also you could send it to Apple a bug report.