# iOS (9.0.2) app rejected saying "On launch the app displays a black screen with no further user functionality."

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, swift2

Apple rejected my app saying `On launch the app displays a black screen with no further user functionality.`

Following was the message in the resolution centre:

> **From Apple**
>
> **2.2 Details**
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 9.0.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> On launch the app displays a black screen with no further user
>   functionality.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> Please run your app on a device to identify the issue(s), then revise
>   and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in the Resolution Center to provide information on how
>   these features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>   For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous
>   version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue(s).
>
> **Resources**
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try
>   testing the workflow described in Technical Q&A QA1764: How to
>   reproduce bugs reported against App Store submissions.
>
> If you have code-level questions after utilizing the above resources,
>   you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When
>   the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>   - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
>   - screenshots
>   - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
>   - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

I archived the same build for Ad Hoc distribution environment and installed on the iPhone as well as on the iPad through iTunes and I did not encounter any black screen. I was able to use my app.

My app is universal with one storyboard.

What could be the reason for the black scree that apple discovered?

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question that may be the cause of your black screen (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219291/black-screen-instead-of-launch-image-on-ipad-ios-7-0-x/19305583#19305583)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app lunch screen will open all device before you submit app in all dimensions landscape and portrait . check all iPhonea devices including small screen devices