# Launch screen is black in iPhone4 with deployment target 7.0 and Xcode 7.1-7.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, splash-screen

I have this environment:

OS X EL capitan 10.11.1 | Xcode 7.1 and test in real device iPhone4 with iOS 7.1

My Deployment target is 7.0 and use Assets Catalog for Launch Screen and images.

[image: App Icons]

[image: Launch Image Information]

I don't have any problems in iOS 8 and 9 but in iOS 7 i have Black screen.

I tried several answers found in Stackoverflow as:
1) Use LaunchScreen.storyboard
2) Add info.plist "Launch screen interface file base name"
3) Remove complete LaunchScreen completely.

All with no success.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After install Xcode 7.2 I'm still have a problem but I use this workaround.

Unselected IOS 7 and later options and left IOS 6.0 and Prior (believe it or not).

[image]

For IOS 8 and later add LaunchScreen with AutoLayout.

[image]

The only trade off is a warning for a mandatory iPhone image inside Launch Screen Catalog but prefer this warning instead black screen in iOS 7.

[This thread help me a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219291/black-screen-instead-of-launch-image-on-ipad-ios-7-0-x).