# After updating to Xcode 10.2 build gets black screen on testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, screen, testflight

I had my app working perfectly. I've updated the Xcode to the latest 10.2 version and something weird happened (as usual with any update...)

The app runs smoothly on the debugger. No issues at all!

When I archive a version to testflight, that version shows the splashscreen then goes into black screen (without crashing) just stays in the black screen... does anyone know what might be happening here?

thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't seem to be issue with update. Which screen is suppose to load after launch screen. Try one more thing deep clean your project `cmd+shift+k` and then run on debugger, you might face issue on debugging as well and then it will be easy to fix.

Comment: I tried that :( didn't work. I even tried on simulator it works fine too... Deleted the app on the device installed a clean install works fine too... just the testflight version gets the black screen.
It is supposed to go to a loading page right after the splash. (check if its logged and such... then redirect to the correct storyboard) but it stays all black

Comment: I added a line to force crash the app so I could get the crash log and try to figure out what the F is happening and it doesn't crash!.. just a fade to black after splashcreen. the force crash should happen. so it doesn't even run the code on the opening viewController

Answer (score 3):

xcode 11.6
@ionic/react capacitor app

I am not expert or anything, I just come up some solutions at web even i still have same problem. Maybe these could help someone.

These are some trouble shooting for that "TestFlight Black screen" issue, looks like something happening storyBoard since they(xcode) switch objective-c to swift. You can read detailed issue from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118297?login=true&page=1#621599022) and [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/15559).

First check edit scheme>run>Build configuration , need to be "Release",
after that, I go over [that](https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-a-project-without-storyboard-in-2020-and-without-swifui-82080eb6d13b) article.

These didn't solve my problem, still looking solution. I don't wanna downgrade xcode.

**UPDATED:7/22/2020**

WE finally solved.
issue:We were getting black screen at TestFlight. Did not touch storyboard.

Check config.capacitor.json and see if u have localhost there,
delete URLs under server section..
we(I) forgot our URL localhost still there when we run release, to be honest i did not know that could be problem or never think to check there,
I spent time(days) to check storyBoard suggestions.

Comment: ok. another silly reason--yes i did, dont archive and commit while your `--livereload` and `ionic serve` terminal tabs working :)

Answer (score 2):

Because of iOS 13 and later, app launch different than earlier versions. Using the latest xCode-11, If you run or install the app from TestFlight on iOS 13 it should work but below 13 it will show black or splash screen. Actually `UIApplicationMain` expect a window property in `AppDelegate` which is in iOS-13 inside `SceneDelegate`. So simply add this line of code (declare window property) in your AppDelegate.

Swift:

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Objective-C:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve my problem, it was in the storyboard. only i remove the searchDisplayController references from all places and that working perfect with Xcode 12.2 version.

```
<searchDisplayController id="pWz-So-g6H">   
<connections>   
   <outlet property="delegate" destination="Yci-sd-Mof" id="fjs-ah-jLs"/>   
   <outlet property="searchContentsController" destination="Yci-sd-Mof" id="gQN-1r-gti"/>   
   <outlet property="searchResultsDataSource" destination="Yci-sd-Mof" id="2Jf-lh-Ute"/>  
   <outlet property="searchResultsDelegate" destination="Yci-sd-Mof" id="Hap-SA-f02"/>   
</connections>   
</searchDisplayController>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find what was going on... so i fixed it by installing xcode 10.1... it works again.. so it's an Xcode 10.2 issue

Comment: I've started a thread on Xcode Forums but still no solution... https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/357452#357452