# Launch Images in iOS7 not appearing

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I'm having all kinds of fun and games with trying to get launch images to appear in Xcode5/iOS7.

I'm using the Sparrow framework but this is an issue I think just to do with XCode5/iOS7.

I don't seem to be able to get Default-568h@2x.png to appear. I can get Default@2x.png to appear but not the 568 version. I Add the 568h file to the assets folder (in system), I then go into the general tab and click on the little folder icon and add it in, and it appears when I click the eye icon. And there is an entry in the UILaunchImages object for it with the launch name being correct "Default-568h". When I run the 4 inch simulator it's just a black/blank screen on loading.

The only thing I can think of is that the other UILaunchImages objects are somehow linked? and that it just takes 1 default name and runs with it so to speak? but then that means you just have to name everything the same name, but with different resolutions??

*Update*

Been reading this...

[Launch Images in iOS 7 with Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758882/launch-images-in-ios-7-with-xcode-5)

Looks like there are issues with using launch images. Going to try to use an Asset Catalogue.

*Update 2*
So far using the Asset Catelogue is not work for 568. Still works fine for 640x960, but even though I've dragged in the Default-568h@2x.png into the R4 slot, when I run the iPhone 5 sim, nothing is showing.

Comment: "Default-568h" is already used for retina display. The "@2x" version of a retina display doesn't exists, so XCode doesn't load your Default-568h@2x.png because it simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I thought iOS7 didn't bother with the different extensions anyway? and it's just what you put in the lunch image name entry that matters?

Comment: If you're using an asset catalog the naming shouldn't matter. Mine are named like Default-568h@2x.png but I don't have info plist entries for launch images.

Comment: It depends: if you put directly the image named "Default-568h@2x.png" XCode should load the correct version, if you put the image named "Default-568h.png" XCode won't load the @2x version because the standard image is already for retina display. :)

Comment: @DavidCaunt Caunt I'm not using an asset catelogue, but I am using the folder buttons in the launch images section in the general tab to add the launch images, and it's automatically creating an entry in the .plist

Comment: @MarcoPace Ok so you're saying just using Default-568h.png ? Just tried this, but XCode won't let me load it, it does however create a new entry in UILaunchImages every time I try to load it.

Comment: If you are creating an app for iphone, you have to create 3 different imges: Default (320x480); Default@2x (640x960); Default-568h. In XCode select the Default image and simply add the other to the project: XCode will load the correct one based on device used to start the application.