# Launch Images not loading in iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I don't know why launch image not loading in my app.

[image]

and this one

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The name of the loading images need to be Default/Default@2x etc.

Comment: @Seya—nope, if you’re using image catalogs (see the last screenshot) then Xcode can set up the appropriate Info.plist keys for you.

Comment: @Noah Witherspoon, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I have Default.png / Default@2x.png / Default-568h@2x.png and I'm using asset catalogs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758882/launch-images-in-ios-7-with-xcode-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Images
Universal apps must provide launch images for both the iPhone and iPad. Typically you have to include one launch image in a portrait orientation for iPhone apps, as well as, iPad apps.

iPhone apps require only one launch image in a portrait orientation, whereas iPad apps typically require different images for portrait and landscape orientations. In brief, you have to provide the following launch images for universal app:

launch image for non-retina iPhone (320×480)
launch image for retina iPhone 4 and 4S (640×960)
launch image for retina iPhone 5 (640×1136)
launch image for non-retina iPad (1024×768)
launch image for retina iPad (2048×1536)

Xcode 5 introduces Asset Catalogs that simplifies management of launch images and app icons. Under the General settings of your target, you should find the App Icons and Launch Images sections.

[image]

Tap the arrow button of Launch Images to access the launch image set. The launch image set contains all the representations of the static launch image that the app displays during launch. You can simply drag the image from Finder and set it into appropriate image well.

[image]

For requirements of launch image, you can further refer to the [Apple’s iOS Human Interface Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

Link:[ios-univeral-app-tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-univeral-app-tutorial/)