# Launches images don't work with asset catalog

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I've worked on this for many hours, but for some reason I can't get launch images to show up on iPhone devices using the asset catalog. The same images will show up on iPad devices and if I switch to not using asset catalog the same images will work on iPhone devices, but not the iPad. I cleaned the folder, deleted the app, and reinstalled it on the iPhone and my iPad devices, but nothing works. I've taken screen shots below. Please help!

Also, my app icons work perfectly using the asset catalogs on all devices and the launch images all work on the iOS simulator.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twpq4.png)

[image]

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCwi4.png)

[image]

[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWZ8i.png)

[image]

Comment: duplicates  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758882/launch-images-in-ios-7-with-xcode-5

Comment: @iDev : here the problem is by using asset catalogs, not `Info.plist`
@Gordon R. Snurr III : do you have any warning related to your app launch image size?

Comment: @iDev: I had seen that link before I posted my question here and it did not solve my issue.

Comment: check your image dimension

Comment: @iDev: Checked. Dimensions are correct.

Comment: which version of os not display the lunch image either all or ios 7 only

Comment: @iDev: They all show up on the iOS simulator. However, none of them show up when testing on an actual iPhone device.

Comment: @iDev: Actually, let me confirm this.

Comment: @iDev: We are on to something now. It's just 7.0 that is having the issue.

Comment: what is dimension to you for ios 7

Comment: Default-568h@2x.png is 640 x 1136

Comment: Default@2x.png is 640 x 960

Comment: Default.png is 320 x 480

Comment: Seems to be a lot of bugs with iOS 7 launch images. I found this and it worked, sort of:

Comment: Navigate to General tab in your project settings, iPhone Device Orientation section and deselect checkboxes beside Landscape Left and Landscape Right, and select Portrait orientation.
Run the app on iPhone 3.5 or 4 iOS 7 simulator with this settings. The app could crash if you have hardcoded Landscape masks somewhere in your app's view controllers, but it does not matter.
Put checkmarks back for Landscape Left and Landscape Right, but leave Portrait orientation allowed as well. That is you should allow Portrait and both Landscape orientations for iPhone.

Comment: However, once I went through this process. The image no longer looks correct when I have the status bar active during launch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check for any duplicate image files in the bundle. If two files are there with the same name, then this issue can occcur.

Comment: I've made this search several times and found no duplicates, but I will check again and let you know. Will be about 1230-1am EST before I can get a response back to you.

Comment: No duplicates found. I wish it was that simple.

Comment: Partially. I did the above instructions I found, but I can't get the status bar to show correctly though, so I have it disabled. Still looking for a better solution. I'll post again below this what I did, but from what I can tell iOS 7 launch images are still very buggy as many people have reported these issues.

Comment: Navigate to General tab in your project settings, iPhone Device Orientation section and deselect checkboxes beside Landscape Left and Landscape Right, and select Portrait orientation. Run the app on iPhone 3.5 or 4 iOS 7 simulator with this settings. The app could crash if you have hardcoded Landscape masks somewhere in your app's view controllers, but it does not matter. Put checkmarks back for Landscape Left and Landscape Right, but leave Portrait orientation allowed as well. That is you should allow Portrait and both Landscape orientations for iPhone. – Gordon R. Snurr III Jan 17 at 7:45

Comment: My application is landscape only.

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly, but we had the same issue and it turned out that clients had submitted JPG instead of PNG images. Once we found out (because we couldn't open a jpg type with extension png in photoshop) it was an easy fix to simply re-save images as true png.

This will probably by a very minority of you guys having this issue, but thought I'd add it just in case.