# Validation of iOS App failing from -568h launch which is there

Tags: ios, validation

I have an app that 2 binaries; a full game and a Lite one.  I have successfully validated and submitted the full game but the Lite one keeps insisting that I do not have the iPhone 5 launch image when Validating it, which I do (named LiteDefault-568h@2x.png following on from the Launch Image name in the Info.plist).  The image is set in exactly the same way as the full game, which validated fine.

(It also keeps trying to rename it to ~iphone.png when I add it to the Launch Images and then have to rename it in the file list).

This is pretty much the last hurdle that is being thrown at me; I am not sure how to upload a screenshot to this question as images only seem to work from web links.

Can anyone suggest what I may be missing?  The image dimensions are correct at 640x1136.

Comment: Hi, do you store your images in images.xcassets file?

Comment: Do you have multiple targets for lite/full version of the game? Then make sure that the images is included in the lite target.

Comment: BraveS, I am not sure about the images.xcassets file.
The image is definitely included in the lite version of the game; I deleted it and recopied it over to make sure.

Comment: (Check the targets as @rckoenes said)
As for images.xcassets. I had similar issue, when I used this file - it worked for me.
See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18856250/1040347)

Comment: It worked!!!  Would you like to add your comment as the answer?

Comment: Actually it was transfer to xcassets that made it work; the image was already assigned to the correct target. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move all your images to the images.xcassets file.
See the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856250/1040347)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple target makes sure that the assets are in include in the target you intend to use them.

In you case make sure the `LiteDefault-568h@2x.png` ins include in the lite target.